# macOS php sqlsrv drivers installed but throwing unknown exception

Tags: php, sql-server, macos-high-sierra

I'm developing PHP apps and now with GIT and all we're supposed to be running locally the apps we develop, while connecting to the company's SQL server for data. I can otherwise see this SQL server without any problems (from Navicat etc).

(I tried installing XAMPP first, never got it to see the sqlsrv / pdo_sqlsrv drivers, tried these guides as well with a "clean" apache install -and then some more- and in the end I did a clean install of macOS, did these guides from scratch again and here we are now).

So I followed the steps described here
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/developer-get-started/php/mac/

and here
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/installation-tutorial-linux-mac?view=sql-server-2017#installing-the-drivers-on-macos-el-capitan-sierra-and-high-sierra

which are the official guides to going about my task. Apart from that, I configured Apache with SSL certificates and PHP 7.2.8 and everything else works fine.

phpinfo() even shows me that sqlsrv and pdo_sqlsrv load ok.

And then I launch my application, where I get this error message when I try to open a connection to the server:

> Fatal error: sqlsrv_connect: Unknown exception caught. in [file] on line [line]

I'm running version 5.3.0 of both sqlsrv and pdo_sqlsrv pecl packages, so I should be past the problems mentioned about version 4.1.7 or before that.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Can you please show the code, and also check the server error logs to see if there's any more information there.

Comment: This is the code I'm using for the connetion:

Comment: try {
 $connectionInfo = array(
  "Database" => $db,
  "Uid" => $user,
  "PWD" => $pass,
  "CharacterSet" => "UTF-8",
  'ReturnDatesAsStrings' => true
 );
 $conn = sqlsrv_connect($host, $connectionInfo);
} catch(Exception $e) { /* do stuff here */ }

This code has been working fine on our (CentOS) testing & production servers. We recently migrated to GIT from SVN and our workflows now require us to do most of the testing locally, hence my efforts to run this on macOS.

The error log shows nothing else than the aforementioned Fatal error

Answer (score 1):

ok, to solve my own question:

First, I enabled logging on the sql_srv level. In the php connection parameters I added:

```
$connectionInfo = array(
    "Database" => $db,
    "Uid" => $user,
    "PWD" => $pass,
    "TraceOn" => true, // this line
    "TraceFile" => "sqlsrvtrace.log", // and this line
    "CharacterSet" => "UTF-8",
);
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($host, $connectionInfo);
```

Inspecting this trace log showed me what was going belly-up on my setup. In my case it was something about the characterset or locale the sql_srv was picking up from the system, so I added the appropriate definition and the problem was solved.